# Python Regex negation forces character to be present

Tags: python, regex, pandas, regex-negation

I'm trying to create a regex to match numbers 1-12 for the months of year(where the first digit is optional) and 1-31 for days of the month without appending all the numbers from 1 to 12.(Just imagine memory if this was for 1 - 1million)

```
pd.Series(["some text8some text","some text13some text", "05"]).str.extract('(?P<mm>[1][012]|(?:[0])?[1-9])')
```

Works on the 8 properly but on 13 instead of ignoring it matches to 1. 
So I tried

```
pd.Series(["some text8some text","13some text", "05"]).str.extract('(?P<mm>[1][012]|(?:[0])?[1-9][^0-9])')
```

But it forces me to have a character after 8 otherwise does not match.

Could someone please help with this regex negation which is forcing me to have a character after 8 to match?

The desired output for this is

```
0: 8
1: Nan 
2: 5
```

Since there is no whitespace, word boundary will not work thus forcing us to use regex-negation.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Give us an input example and desired output?

Comment: Yes the desired output for 8 is 8 and output for 13 is Nan. Thanks, i'll edit the question

Comment: It is different from those questions though :| The original intent was for an intuitive was to use regex negation, since it need not have a word boundary or whitespace character separating the text from the number. However the alternative solution will work fine I hope on the dataset. Thanks @Jan

Comment: There is no whitespace to be used as word boundary

Comment: @dev: Have a look here with lookarounds: https://regex101.com/r/kFnIsJ/1

Comment: @Jan Thanks so much! regex101 is really helpful and I kept digging to find `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21300197/python-regex-to-find-whitespace-end-of-string-and-or-word-boundary` which may be of use to someone. I'm new to this lookup and discovered the forms of negative lookup to write crisp regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use anchors or word boundaries:

```
\b(?:1[0-2]|[1-9])\b
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/vpMA85/3).

---

With `pandas` this might be:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.Series(["8","13", "text in between 13 as well", "here is an 8 hidden"]).str.extract(r'(?P<mm>\b(?:1[0-2]|[1-9])\b)') 
print(df)
```

This yields

```
0      8
1    NaN
2    NaN
3      8
Name: mm, dtype: object
```

Comment: No, I have data such that the numbers could be in between text

Comment: @dev: Then use word boundaries, have updated the answer and the demo.

Comment: I'm sorry, after executing it does not match 8

Comment: @dev: Yes, it does, check the code.

Comment: It does not work with word boundaries.. See this `pd.Series(["8","13", "text in between13as well", "here is an8hidden"]).str.extract(r'(?P<mm>\b(?:1[0-2]|[1-9])\b)') ` does not match the hidden 8. There is no whitespace to be used as word boundary. Thanks for the help though @Jan